# Remote Testing with a physical hardware next to it

Tags: flutter, testing, remote-debugging

We have a client here who has a mobile app in Flutter (works on both iOS and Android)
He also has actual custom hardware that the mobile app interacts with via Bluetooth
I want to see if there's any product/service/open source tool in the market that would allow us to control an iPhone remotely so that a dev can debug and test the mobile app from overseas while interacting with the physical hardware next to it.

I've done a quick search and it's not a trivial thing to find out there but I'm sure something must exist because testing platforms like BrowserStack and AWS DeviceFarm actually provide it for their own iOS devices

Comment: Kindly please check this documentation regarding flutter iOS automation for remote real devices on BrowserStack: 
ios- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/flutter-ios/getting-started
android- https://www.browserstack.com/docs/app-automate/flutter/getting-started


if you still have any issues or queries, just email to support@browserstack.com